# Create element in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I am using the Selenium plugin to test my javascript code. Part of my code is that, onclick anywhere on the document body, a div is created and placed there. It works fine when I click myself, but after the click action on a selenium test case, nothing is created and I'm left with an error. Is this some missing feature of selenium, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please share your code first which have you tried and also share the exception which you are getting...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I uploaded a screenshot of what's appearing

Comment: Looks like the element isn't ready yet since it is saying the element isn't found.  Normally you have to wait till the page is ready before you interact with it.  In code, you would wait till the element is visible and then click.

Comment: Yes, I slowed down the speed and added a pause command after clicking, thank you for your help!